# C++: Why this Smart Dynamically Pointer are not available?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

When I run line B, everything seems OK but when I swap it for line A, it crashed, and I don't know why.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> vi(10,5);
  auto ptr = make_shared<vector<int>>(vi); //A
  // auto ptr = &vi; //B
  auto beg = ptr->begin();
  while (beg != vi.end())
    cout << *beg++ << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create your question with code and with the explanation of what is the problem. Not with a link to something.

Comment: Please include the listing of the program in the description, nobody wants to look images of code..

Comment: In addition to not wanting to look at images; when someone else comes to search for the same problem, they'll not be able to find it; or if they do somehow manage to find this page from your question, your code will no longer be available.

Comment: Sorry about that image problem, sense the first time I don't know about how to write the code correctly, that's my fault, sorry everybody.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `ptr->begin()` and `vi.end()`. When *ptr is vi, thats fine, but your `make_shared<vector<int>>(vi)` line actually calls the copy constructor and creates a new copy of vi.

If you really need to create a shared_ptr into the stack you need to create it like this:

```
auto ptr = shared_ptr<vector<int>>(&vi, [](vector<int>*){}); //A
```

This gives the shared_ptr an empty deleter, so it won't try to delete anything off the stack (which would cause a crash).

Note: this is almost always a bad idea, since it violates the whole purpose of the shared_ptr; it no longer owns anything. This makes things confusing to debug. You need to make sure that the stack vector *definitely* lives longer than whatever uses the shared_ptr or your app will crash.